# Comparing rates of change with unequal and unevenly spaced timepoints

Tags: linear-model, normalization, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am trying to compare rates of change in my data and although the units of time are the same, some instances have more/less time points than others and the time points are not uniform. Is there some normalization I need to do to account for these differences? I.E. in this toy example are 1.26 and .96 comparable?

```
 data1 = c(3,6,11)

 time_from_baseline1 = c(0,2,8)

 data2 = c(2,4,8,15)

 time_from_baseline2 = c(0,1,5,10)

 coef(lm(data1 ~ time_from_baseline1))
        (Intercept) time_from_baseline1 
          3.4615385           0.9615385 

 coef(lm(data2 ~ time_from_baseline2))
        (Intercept) time_from_baseline2 
           2.217742            1.258065
```

I understand that instances with more time points should have more accurate rates of change but is there even a way to correct for this?

Comment: What are you trying to model?  For linear regression (the `lm` function) it doesn't matter.  If this is time series data and you are going to use a time series model, then you want to lookup [unevenly spaced time series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unevenly_spaced_time_series).

Comment: Yeah just an lm. That is what I thought a slope is a slope regardless of how much data there is. Thanks.